# Command pattern with cross dependency

Tags: c#, assemblies, command-pattern

I have three assemblies:

- Core with basic stuffs, utility classes, etc
- Network that receives and send packets
- Game that take all the informations and compute them

I'd like to use a command pattern to exchange informations between Game and Network and keep the Game commands (create stuff, move something, etc) in Game and the Network command (request this, update that) in Network.
This does not seems like much, but it leads to a mutual dependency between Game and Network and I can't find a clean solution to this.

I'd appreciate advice, articles, example code, anything basically!

Comment: Do you mean that game commands will depend on network commands and vice versa? Why? Could you give an example?

Comment: The commands sent to Game need references of objects from the Game assembly and will affect Game objects only. I'd like the Network to be able to create such commands without referencing the Game assembly.

Comment: You could inject a builder as a dependency. If you could post some sample code it will be easier to help you.